# MDT - Disable auto login of default administrator account in the task sequence

Tags: windows, windows-7, autologin, mdt, sysprep

In my task sequence for a deployment of a captured image of Windows 7 Pro, I have a step that disables the default administrator account. I also have a step that elevates another account dubbed 'localadmin' as an administrator. Unfortunately it's not my call, so I can't just rename the existing administrator account to localadmin. Both steps are at the end of the task sequence, the disabling step being the very last proceeded by a restart. Before switching from purely WDS to MDT, I did all this before capturing the image and the disabled administrator account and the elevated localadmin account both survived sysprep and capture. But with MDT, the sysprep strips the admin rights of localadmin and re-enables the default administrator account which it uses to log in with during the sequence, hence my extra steps. So when the task sequence is over I get the following message at the login screen: "Your account has been disabled. Please see your system administrator." instead of it defaulting to the localadmin login. It appears it is trying to auto login. How do I get around this in the task sequence?